# select all from a JPQL query, with paremeters

Tags: java, sql, database, jpa, jpql

I have selection parameters on flat data, only don't know how to either omit a parameter entirely, or make it a complete wildcard.  The search might use one or all parameters.  How is this done?  With `ANY` or `ALL`?  Or, is there another way?

I would like to use one general query with all the paremeters, and pass in "all" or "any", something along those lines, for **some** of those parameters.

existing code:

```
package legacy.database;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;

public class MyQueries {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyQueries.class.getName());
    private final EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("LegacyDatabasePU");
    private final EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    public MyQueries() {
    }

    public List<Clients> findAll() {
        Query q = em.createQuery("select c from Clients c");
       List<Clients> clients = q.getResultList();
        return clients;
    }

    public List<Clients> selectWithParameters(Criteria c) {
        log.info(c.toString());
        String opener = c.getOpener();
        String closer1 = c.getCloser1();
        String status = c.getStatus();
        Query q = em.createQuery(
                "SELECT c FROM Clients c "
                + "WHERE c.status like :status "
                + "and c.closer1 like :closer1 "
                + "and c.opener like :opener");
        q.setParameter("opener", opener);
        q.setParameter("closer1", closer1);
        q.setParameter("status", status);
        log.info(q.toString());
        List<Clients> clients = q.getResultList();
        log.fine(clients.toString());
        return clients;
    }

    public Clients findById(int id) {
        Clients client = em.find(Clients.class, id);
        return client;
    }

    public void send(int id) {
        Clients c = em.find(Clients.class, id);
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
        Timestamp t = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        c.setDateUpdated(t.toString());
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case the parameters are optional, the criteria API provides some more flexibility.
If the *selectWithParameters* is called often, consider using parameters, since the DB can cache the parametrized query then.

*selectWithParameters* with optional parameters reads like this:

```
public List<Clients> selectWithParameters(Criteria criteria) {
    log.info(criteria.toString());
    String opener = criteria.getOpener();
    String closer1 = criteria.getCloser1();
    String status = criteria.getStatus();

    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Clients> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Clients.class);
    Root<Clients> c = query.from(Clients.class);
    List<Predicate> wherePredicates = new LinkedList<Predicate>();
    if (null != status) {
        wherePredicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(c.get("status"), status));
    }
    if (null != closer1) {
        wherePredicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(c.get("closer1"), closer1));
    }
    if (null != opener) {
        wherePredicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(c.get("opener"), opener));
    }
    query.where(wherePredicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));

    List<Clients> clients = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    log.fine(clients.toString());
    return clients;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, Heiner.  This worked, not sure why I had trouble with Heiner's code, but his sample put me in the right direction:

```
public List<Clients> selectByCriteria(Criteria criteria) {
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Clients> clientCriteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Clients.class);
    Root<Clients> clientRoot = clientCriteriaQuery.from(Clients.class);
    clientCriteriaQuery.select(clientRoot);
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(clientRoot.get(Clients_.phone1), "%" + criteria.getPhone1() + "%"));
    if (!criteria.getOpener().equalsIgnoreCase("all")) {
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(clientRoot.get(Clients_.opener), "%" + criteria.getOpener() + "%"));
    }
    if (!criteria.getCloser1().equalsIgnoreCase("all")) {
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(clientRoot.get(Clients_.closer1), "%" + criteria.getCloser1() + "%"));
    }
    if (!criteria.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("all")) {
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(clientRoot.get(Clients_.status), "%" + criteria.getStatus() + "%"));
    }
    clientCriteriaQuery.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    List<Clients> clients = em.createQuery(clientCriteriaQuery).getResultList();
    return clients;
}
```

There's probably no substantive difference (?) from what Heiner answered.  JPA and JPQL are a bit murky.  I can't believe it, but I almost prefer SQL!  I'll have to adjust.